# How do I restrict the search index to only titles?

Tags: drupal, search

I have a site with many nodes. I want to keep both titles and bodies, but not to index bodies for performance and agility.
So, is there any way or module to do this?

Comment: Can you specify version of Drupal?

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 6:

In _node_index_node function of node module is:

```
$text = '<h1>' . check_plain($node->title) . '</h1>' . $node->body;
```

Probably changing this line is the only way.

[Source](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/_node_index_node/6)

Maybe you should consider and find how to turn off CCK fields data indexing?

Comment: Thanks! but it need to change the node.module, do you have a better solution that not need to modify the core code?

Comment: Unfortunately not, drupal doesn't provide any hook for this.